# Add button doesn't add text to UITextView in swift

Tags: swift

I'm testing the my add button in the view controller file.  It should go to validateName function in my model file and which returns true and then enables my addButton.  But when I click on "Add" it doesn't change the text of the UITextView.

In viewcontroller.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate{
    @IBOutlet weak var nameInputText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameInputText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordInputText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneInputText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailInputText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var textviewText: UITextView!

    let model = Model()

    @IBAction func addButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        textviewText.text = "hi"
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
                   shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
                   replacementString string: String)
        -> Bool
    {
        addButton.isEnabled = false

        let text: String = nameInputText.text!
        var test_name:  Bool
        var name_array = [String]()
        test_name = model.validateName(nametext: text)
        if test_name == true{
            addButton.isEnabled = true
            name_array.append(text)
            return true
        }

        return (true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        usernameInputText.delegate = self
        nameInputText.delegate = self
        passwordInputText.isSecureTextEntry = true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event:    UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
        usernameInputText.resignFirstResponder()
        nameInputText.resignFirstResponder()
        return (true)
    }
}
```

//In model.swift:

```
import Foundation

class Model {
    func validateName(nametext: String) -> Bool{
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `addButton` function is triggered and `textviewText.text = "hi"` is executed?

Comment: that's what I'm not sure of.

Comment: put a break point on that line and then click on the button to see if that code is executed

Comment: Started over with it and now it's working I think!